# TypeScript + NW.js: need namespaces for browser, need commonjs for nodejs - How do I get both?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nw.js

I'm writing an application using NW.js and TypeScript.  I would like to use one class per file.

To access node.js modules, I need to use `require()`.  However, the `document` context within a `require()`d module is no longer the browser's `document` context.

It seems to me that I need to stick to namespaces to be able to access the browser DOM from my application.

How can I combine those two module styles in one TypeScript application?  When trying to use `namespace` together with `require`, my types suddenly lose visibility across files (because the compiler goes into *external module mode*.)

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to me that I need to stick to namespaces to be able to access the browser DOM from my application

No. You can use a module loader like webpack to bundle the portions that the browser needs into a single `bundle.js` while still keeping *all your code base in `commonjs` mode*.

## More

A quickstart is available : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

## More More

I am actually creating an OSS editor that demonstrates this : http://alm.tools/. The whole project (backend + server) has a *single* `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  Could you include a short version of the solution in the answer, in addition to the link?  Also, how does webpack know which require not to execute and pass on to NW.js's node.js environment?

Comment: The more is completely not needed. The answer is use a module loader e.g. webpack. You don't have to use webpack you can use browserify.

Comment: `how does webpack know`. Because it understands the commonjs module system

Comment: webpack does not work for me to `require` node.js modules, mixed with frontend browser modules.  Understandably it tells me `Cannot resolve module` - how would it know that a given module (say, `events`) will be provided by node.js?

Comment: the *nodejs* specific modules should not be loaded in the frontend

Comment: In NW.js there is only the frontend - there is no separation as it is in electron.